Stop location updates in Kotlin Jetpack Compose Android Studio
I'm developing an app with Kotlin Jetpack Compose according to the MVVM pattern.
I would like the position to be acquired only when the user is on the home page, so when he moves to other screens the updates should be stopped.
I am sharing the file relating to the position so that you can see how it is structured:
Posizione.kt
class Posizione(private val context: Context) {

    // FusedLocationProviderClient è utilizzato per ottenere aggiornamenti sulla posizione
    var fusedLocationProviderClient: FusedLocationProviderClient =
        LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(context)

    // callback che riceve gli aggiornamenti della posizione
    private lateinit var locationCallback: LocationCallback

    // configurazione delle richieste di posizione
    private var locationRequest: LocationRequest = LocationRequest.create().apply {
        interval = 10000 // aggiornamento posizione ogni 10 secondi
        fastestInterval = 5000 // intervallo più veloce tra gli aggiornamenti di posizione
        priority = LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY // alta precisione
    }

    // gestisce gli aggiornamenti di posizione
    private var locationUpdateListener: ((Location) -> Unit)? = null

    init {
        setupLocationCallback() // inizializza il callback della posizione
    }

    // configura il callback che gestisce gli aggiornamenti della posizione
    private fun setupLocationCallback() {
        locationCallback = object : LocationCallback() {
            override fun onLocationResult(locationResult: LocationResult) {
                super.onLocationResult(locationResult)
                for (location in locationResult.locations) {
                    Log.d(
                        "POSIZIONE",
                        "Posizione attuale: lat ${location.latitude}, lon ${location.longitude}"
                    )
                    locationUpdateListener?.invoke(location)
                }
            }
        }
        Log.d("POSIZIONE", "Callback di posizione configurato")
    }

    fun setLocationUpdateListener(update: (Location) -> Unit) {
        locationUpdateListener = update
    }

    // controlla se i permessi di posizione sono stati concessi
    fun checkPermissions(): Boolean {
        val fineLocationPermission =
            ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
        val coarseLocationPermission =
            ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)
        val permissionsGranted =
            fineLocationPermission == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && coarseLocationPermission == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED

        Log.d("POSIZIONE", "Permessi di localizzazione concessi: $permissionsGranted")
        return permissionsGranted
    }

    // Avvia gli aggiornamenti della posizione se i permessi sono stati concessi
    fun startLocationUpdates() {
        if (!checkPermissions()) {
            Log.d("POSIZIONE", "Permessi di localizzazione non concessi, richiesta in corso...")
            return
        }
        startLocationUpdatesWithPermission()
    }

    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    fun startLocationUpdatesWithPermission() {
        Log.d("POSIZIONE", "Inizio aggiornamenti della posizione con permessi concessi")
        try {
            fusedLocationProviderClient.requestLocationUpdates(
                locationRequest,
                locationCallback,
                Looper.getMainLooper()
            )
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Log.e("POSIZIONE", "Errore durante la richiesta degli aggiornamenti della posizione", e)
        }
    }

    // Interrompe gli aggiornamenti della posizione
    fun stopLocationUpdates() {
        Log.d("POSIZIONE", "Interruzione aggiornamenti della posizione")
        try {
            fusedLocationProviderClient.removeLocationUpdates(locationCallback)
            Log.d("POSIZIONE", "Callback rimosso per gli aggiornamenti della posizione")
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Log.e("POSIZIONE", "Errore durante la rimozione degli aggiornamenti della posizione", e)
        }
    }

    // controlla la visualizzazione o meno del pulsante di attivazione dell'oggetto (in InfoOggettoScreen) e restituisce il raggio di attivazione (utilizzato nella HomeScreen ma recuperato da HomeViewModel)
    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    suspend fun bottoneAttivazione(
        oggettoLat: Double,
        oggettoLon: Double
    ): Pair<Boolean, Double> {

        var raggio: Double = 100.0

        // posizione attuale del dispositivo (è una chiamata asincrona)
        val posizioneUtente = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            fusedLocationProviderClient.lastLocation.await()
        }
        if (posizioneUtente != null) {
            Log.d(
                "Bottone Attivazione",
                "Posizione utente: lat ${posizioneUtente.latitude}, lon ${posizioneUtente.longitude}"
            )
        } else {
            Log.d("Bottone Attivazione", "Posizione utente nulla")
        }

        // distanza tra utente e oggetto
        val calcoloDistanza = FloatArray(1)
        if (posizioneUtente != null) {
            Location.distanceBetween(
                posizioneUtente.latitude,
                posizioneUtente.longitude,
                oggettoLat,
                oggettoLon,
                calcoloDistanza
            )
        }
        val distanza = calcoloDistanza[0]
        Log.d("Bottone Attivazione", "Distanza tra oggetto e utente: $distanza")

        val sid =
            Credenziali(context).getCredenziali().first.toString() // recupero il sid dal database
        val uid =
            Credenziali(context).getCredenziali().second?.toInt() // recupero l'uid dal database
        val utente = Api.api.getUsersID(uid!!, sid) // recupero le informazioni dell'utente

        if (utente.amulet != null) {
            Log.d("Bottone Attivazione", "Amuleto equipaggiato")

            val amuleto =
                Api.api.getObjectsID(utente.amulet, sid) // recupero le informazioni dell'amuleto
            Log.d("Bottone Attivazione", "Info amuleto: $amuleto")

            if (amuleto.level != null) {
                raggio *= (1 + (amuleto.level / 100.0)) // aumento il raggio di attivazione dell'amuleto (secondo la proporzione)
            }
        } else { // amuleto non equipaggiato (il raggio rimane 100)
            Log.d("Bottone Attivazione", "Amuleto non equipaggiato")
        }

        Log.d("Bottone Attivazione", "Raggio di attivazione: $raggio")
        Log.d("Bottone Attivazione", "distanza <= raggio: ${distanza <= raggio}")

        return Pair(distanza <= raggio, raggio)

    }

}

I tried to achieve what I described in the HomeScreen with DisposableEffect but I couldn't.:
DisposableEffect(navController) {
        val listener = NavController.OnDestinationChangedListener { _, destination, _ ->
            if (destination.route != "home") {
                viewModel.stopLocationUpdates()
            } else {
                viewModel.startLocationUpdates()
            }
        }
        navController.addOnDestinationChangedListener(listener)
        onDispose {
            navController.removeOnDestinationChangedListener(listener)
        }
    }

This is the ViewModel file:
class HomeViewModel : ViewModel() {

    private val _posizioneUtente = MutableStateFlow<LatLng?>(null)
    val posizioneUtente: StateFlow<LatLng?> = _posizioneUtente.asStateFlow()
    private lateinit var locationProvider: Posizione

    private val _oggettiVirtuali = MutableStateFlow<List<GetObjects>>(emptyList())
    val oggettiVirtuali: StateFlow<List<GetObjects>> = _oggettiVirtuali.asStateFlow()

    private val _utentiVicini = MutableStateFlow<List<GetUsers>>(emptyList())
    val utentiVicini: StateFlow<List<GetUsers>> = _utentiVicini.asStateFlow()

    private val _raggioAzione = MutableStateFlow<Int>(100)
    val raggioAzione: StateFlow<Int> = _raggioAzione.asStateFlow()

    private val _puntiVita = MutableStateFlow<Int>(100)
    val puntiVita: StateFlow<Int> = _puntiVita.asStateFlow()
    private val _puntiEsperienza = MutableStateFlow<Int>(0)
    val puntiEsperienza: StateFlow<Int> = _puntiEsperienza.asStateFlow()

    private val _isLoading = MutableStateFlow(false)
    val isLoading: StateFlow<Boolean> = _isLoading.asStateFlow()

    private var updateJob: Job? = null

    fun initialize(context: Context) {
        locationProvider = Posizione(context.applicationContext)

        locationProvider.setLocationUpdateListener { location ->
            updateJob?.cancel()

            _isLoading.value = true
            updateJob = viewModelScope.launch {
                _posizioneUtente.value = LatLng(location.latitude, location.longitude)

                val sid = Credenziali(context).getCredenziali().first.toString()
                val lat = location.latitude
                val lon = location.longitude

                launch {
                    oggetti(context, sid, lat, lon)
                }

                launch {
                    utenti(sid, lat, lon)
                }

                if (_oggettiVirtuali.value.isNotEmpty()) {
                    var (_, raggio) = Posizione(context).bottoneAttivazione(
                        _oggettiVirtuali.value.first().lat,
                        _oggettiVirtuali.value.first().lon
                    )
                    _raggioAzione.value = raggio.toInt()
                    Log.d("HomeViewModel", "Raggio d'azione aggiornato: ${_raggioAzione.value}")
                }

                aggiornaVitaEdEsperienza(
                    sid,
                    Credenziali(context).getCredenziali().second!!.toInt(),
                )
            }
            _isLoading.value = false
        }

        startLocationUpdates()

        val credenziali = Credenziali(context)
        credenziali.verificaECaricaCredenziali(context)
    }

    private suspend fun oggetti(context: Context, sid: String, lat: Double, lon: Double) {
        withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            try {
                val oggettiRicevuti = Api.api.getObjects(sid, lat, lon)
                _oggettiVirtuali.value = oggettiRicevuti

                val database = Database(context)
                database.aggiornaOggettiDB(oggettiRicevuti, Api.api)

                Log.d("HomeViewModel", "getObjects - Oggetti virtuali ricevuti: $oggettiRicevuti")
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                Log.d(
                    "HomeViewModel",
                    "getObjects - Errore durante il caricamento degli oggetti: $e"
                )
            }
        }
    }

    private suspend fun utenti(sid: String, lat: Double, lon: Double) {
        withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            try {
                val utentiRicevuti = Api.api.getUsers(sid, lat, lon)
                _utentiVicini.value = utentiRicevuti

                Log.d("HomeViewModel", "getUsers - Utenti vicini ricevuti: $utentiRicevuti")
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                Log.d("HomeViewModel", "getUsers - Errore durante il caricamento degli utenti: $e")
            }
        }
    }

    private suspend fun aggiornaVitaEdEsperienza(sid: String, uid: Int) {
        val utente = Api.api.getUsersID(uid, sid)

        _puntiVita.value = utente.life
        _puntiEsperienza.value = utente.experience
    }

    fun startLocationUpdates() {
        if (::locationProvider.isInitialized) {
            if (locationProvider.checkPermissions()) {
                locationProvider.startLocationUpdates()
            } else {
                Log.d("HomeViewModel", "startLocationUpdates - Permessi non concessi")
            }
        } else {
            Log.d("HomeViewModel", "startLocationUpdates - Location provider non inizializzato")
        }
    }

    fun stopLocationUpdates() {
        if (::locationProvider.isInitialized) {
            try {
                locationProvider.stopLocationUpdates()
                Log.d("HomeViewModel", "Interruzione aggiornamenti della posizione")
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                Log.e(
                    "HomeViewModel",
                    "Errore durante l'interruzione degli aggiornamenti della posizione",
                    e
                )
            }
        } else {
            Log.w("HomeViewModel", "LocationProvider non è inizializzato")
        }
    }

    fun clear() {
        stopLocationUpdates()
        updateJob?.cancel()
    }

    override fun onCleared() {
        super.onCleared()
        clear()
    }
}

